# Fetch data from Firestore to a table from a document that includes 2 arrays (value and quantity)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a Firestore collection that includes 2 documents meanwhile (could be more).
Every document has 2 arrays (Quantity and value) as shown in the last screenshot below.

I want to get all the data and create every time a row with the data from the document's arrays ***like this:***

[image: Expected result]

***But I'm getting this instead:***

[image: Table]

***Firestore:***

[image: Firestore]

***code:***

```
export default class NutritionTableOfTheUser extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        tableData: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const dbRef = collection(db, 'data');
    onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
        let foods = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            foods.push(doc.data())
        });
        this.setState({ tableData: foods })
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className='container mt-3'>
            {/* table */}
            <table className='table table-hover'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Food</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    {this.state.tableData.map((row, index) => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                                <td>{row.value}</td>
                                <td>{row.quantity}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
onSnapshot(dbRef, (querySnapshot) => {
        let foods = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const {value, quantity} = doc.data()
            for(let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
              foods.push({value: value[i], quantity:quantity[i]})
            }
        });
        this.setState({ tableData: foods })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It resolved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).